# How can I get the error from nestjs to angular with pipe()?

Tags: angular, redux, nestjs, ngxs

Show code

```
 this.authService
  .login(payload)
  .pipe(
    map((e: any) => e.token),
    tap(e => dispatch(new AuthLoginSuccess(e)))
  )
  .subscribe();
```

i am trying to show the error returning from nestjs backend to my angular frontend. The above function returns the  token if the correct credentials are posted. I am not able to obtain the errors

Comment: Please clarify the question, it's not clear exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please add more description to your question and show more code. What does `distpatch(new AuthLoginSuccess(e))` do? What types are there? What does `this.authService.login(payload)` return? What does a mock payload look like?

Comment: am trying to get if any error from nestjs backend to angular frontend

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http#error-handling

Comment: distpatch(new AuthLoginSuccess(e)) is used to do some function after login is success

Comment: please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and clearly state your problem, your question is not clear.

Comment: Add an `error` handler to the subscription i.e `this.authService
  .login(payload)
  .pipe(
    map((e: any) => e.token),
    tap(e => dispatch(new AuthLoginSuccess(e)))
  )
  .subscribe(() => {// success handler}, err => {// error handler});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  .login(payload)
  .pipe(
    map((e: any) => e.token),
    tap(e => dispatch(new AuthLoginSuccess(e))),
    catchError(error => { .... do stuff .... } )
  )
  .subscribe();
```

This should allow you to grab any errors from your service.

Answer (score 1):

With RxJS to catch any errors you need to use the `catchError()` operator, similarly to how you are using `tap` and `map`. The other option is to provide an error observer to the `subscribe()` method and handle it there. Depending on what you want to do with the error, both can be useful.